# Random X session crash

Tags: debian, xorg

My X session just stopped all of a sudden sending me back to login screen.

I was browsing the web, not doing any CPU/memory intensive tasks.

I'm using Debian Jessie / Mint / lightdm / radeon.

Here's what I find in the log files (including `.old` backup versions when applicable). Nothing relevant, except a suspicious line in `lightdm.x-0.log`.

#### `.xsession-errors`

Nothing except a few lines like this which are obvious consequences of the issue I'm dealing with:

```
python3: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
```

#### `Xorg.log`

Nothing different from usual stuff.

#### `syslog`, `kern.log`, `messages`

Nothing relevant.

#### `lightdm/lightdm.log`

```
[+53.35s] DEBUG: Session pid=1566: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+53.53s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+53.53s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session 1
[+39174.20s] DEBUG: Session pid=1566: Exited with return value 0
[+39174.22s] DEBUG: Seat: Session stopped
[+39174.22s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+39174.22s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 892
[+39174.39s] DEBUG: Process 892 terminated with signal 6
[+39174.39s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: X server stopped
[+39174.39s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+39174.39s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+39174.39s] DEBUG: Seat: Display server stopped
[+39174.39s] DEBUG: Seat: Active display server stopped, starting greeter
[+39174.39s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating greeter session
[+39174.40s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating display server of type x
```

#### `lightdm/x-0.log`

```
X: ../../glamor/glamor_vbo.c:70: glamor_get_vbo_space: Assertion `epoxy_glGetError() == 0' failed.
```

Comment: Found related bugreport on [Debian BTS](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=777457) while writing the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I should leave this question open. I found the bug report but the bug is not solved and hard to reproduce. The only added value of having this here is that it might help someone identify the same issue by looking at lightdm logs. I generally check syslog and Xorg.log but I rarely think of lightdm logs.

Comment: Can you see anything interesting in `Xorg.0.log.old`?

Comment: @FerencWágner Nope. I did look there. I wrote Xorg.log in the question as a generic term for Xorg.* I just edited the question to make this explicit.